Upload file to upload folder in Wordpress in a custom plugin
I am trying to develop a custom plugin in WordPress that requires uploading an audio or video file to the uploads folder. However, I cannot get this part of the plugin to work. I have read several tutorials and replicated the code exactly. It works perfectly for them, but not me. I removed all of my code except for a simple file input to test it, but no luck.
When I press the submit button, it simply loads forever and then eventually redirects to a 404 page. It does not create the folder, upload the file, display the error log message, or even submit any ajax request under the Network tab in the dev tools.
When I replace the file input field with a text field instead, and ask it to print the entered text, it works normally. There is something about the file upload field that it does not like.
What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to upload a file to the uploads folder in WordPress using a form?
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyPage
Plugin URI: https://yourwebsite.com/
Description: A plugin to upload audio and video files to the MyPage folder.
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: https://yourwebsite.com/
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

// Hook to add a menu item in the WordPress admin dashboard
add_action('admin_menu', 'myPage_menu');

function myPage_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'MyPage',
        'MyPage',
        'manage_options',
        'myPage',
        'myPage_page',
        'dashicons-media-audio', // Icon for the menu item
    );
}

// Function to display the form on the plugin page
function myPage_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>MyPage</h1>
        <form id="myPage-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
            <input type="file" name="myPage_file" id="myPage_file" accept="audio/*,video/*" required>
            <button type="submit" id="myPage_submit">Upload File</button>
        </form>
        <div id="myPage_message">
            <?php
                // Check if the form has been submitted and handle the file upload
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                    myPage_handle_upload();
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
// Handle file upload on form submission
function myPage_handle_upload() {
    error_log("Function running...");
    if (isset($_FILES['myPage_file'])) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/my-page/';
        if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
            wp_mkdir_p($target_dir); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        }
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['myPage_file']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myPage_file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
            echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
        } else {
            echo 'Error uploading the file.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No file uploaded.';
    }
    wp_die();
    }
?>


The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the way WordPress handles file uploads. When you submit a form with a file input, WordPress doesn't handle it like a normal form submission. Instead, it uses a separate process to handle the file upload.
To fix this issue, you need to use the wp_handle_upload function provided by WordPress to handle the file upload. This function takes care of moving the uploaded file to the correct location and returns an array with information about the uploaded file.
Here's an updated version of your code that uses wp_handle_upload to handle the file upload:
    <?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

// Hook to add a menu item in the WordPress admin dashboard
add_action('admin_menu', 'myPage_menu');

function myPage_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'MyPage',
        'MyPage',
        'manage_options',
        'myPage',
        'myPage_page',
        'dashicons-media-audio', // Icon for the menu item
    );
}

// Function to display the form on the plugin page
function myPage_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>MyPage</h1>
        <form id="myPage-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
            <input type="file" name="myPage_file" id="myPage_file" accept="audio/*,video/*" required>
            <button type="submit" id="myPage_submit">Upload File</button>
        </form>
        <div id="myPage_message">
            <?php
                // Check if the form has been submitted and handle the file upload
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                    myPage_handle_upload();
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Handle file upload on form submission
function myPage_handle_upload() {
    error_log("Function running...");
    if (isset($_FILES['myPage_file'])) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/my-page/';
        if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
            wp_mkdir_p($target_dir); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        }
        $file_data = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['myPage_file'], array('test_form' => false));
        if ($file_data && !isset($file_data['error'])) {
            $file_path = $file_data['file'];
            $file_name = basename($file_path);
            $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
            if (wp_mkdir_p($target_dir)) {
                if (wp_move_uploaded_file($file_path, $target_file)) {
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
                } else {
                    echo 'Error moving the uploaded file.';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Error creating the upload directory.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error uploading the file.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No file uploaded.';
    }
    wp_die();
}
?>

In this updated code, we have used wp_handle_upload to handle the file upload. This function returns an array with information about the uploaded file, including the file path. We then use wp_move_uploaded_file to move the uploaded file to the correct location.
Also, make sure to add the test_form argument to wp_handle_upload and set it to false to prevent WordPress from checking for a valid form submission.
This should fix the issue you're experiencing and allow you to upload files to the my-page directory in the WordPress uploads folder.
